# Rails 7: Font-awesome icons not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, npm, font-awesome

I have a problem. In my Rails 7 application I am trying to use Font-Awesome icons. I have installed [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free) npm package and then added:

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free"
```

to my `app.ts`. After that I checked the page where I have put this icon:

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i>
```

But the icon is not showing up. Going into inspector mode, I can see that the icon has a height and width of 0:0, so something must be wrong with installation, maybe I am missing something. I already tried installing the Font-Awesome gem, instead of the NPM, but that gave me all kinds of errors with ESBuild about not be able to compile .svg files and a few other extensions. What am I missing here with the installation?

### UPDATE

After installing the gem `font-awesome-sass` and running `bundle install`, I added the import statement like this in my app.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error output:

```
✘ [ERROR] [plugin sass-plugin] Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
9 │ @import "font-awesome";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  - 9:9  root stylesheet

/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1596
  let error = new Error(`${text}${summary}`);
              ^

Error: Build failed with 1 error:
error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
9 │ @import "font-awesome";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  - 9:9  root stylesheet
    at failureErrorWithLog (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1596:15)
    at /app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1052:28
    at runOnEndCallbacks (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1468:61)
    at buildResponseToResult (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1050:7)
    at /app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1162:14
    at responseCallbacks.<computed> (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:697:9)
    at handleIncomingPacket (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:752:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/app/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:673:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: null,
      notes: [],
      pluginName: 'sass-plugin',
      text: "Can't find stylesheet to import.\n" +
        '\x1B[34m  ╷\x1B[0m\n' +
        '\x1B[34m9 │\x1B[0m @import \x1B[31m"font-awesome"\x1B[0m;\n' +
        '\x1B[34m  │\x1B[0m \x1B[31m        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\x1B[0m\n' +
        '\x1B[34m  ╵\x1B[0m\n' +
        '  - 9:9  root stylesheet'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}
```

Comment: Is this typo only here or also in your app? (fortawesome = fontawesome)
```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free"
```

Comment: `import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see! How strange :)
This is how I have it:

```
gem "font-awesome-sass", "~> 6.1" 
bundle install
```

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
```

and icons (FontAwesome 5.15.4 and Free icons that have fas fa-something) work perfectly this way:

```
 <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
```

but they don't work if I want to use unicode icons as content in ::before and and ::after pseudo selectors. After testing on font awesome's own code on codepen and seeing that unicode icons didn't work if the stack was font awesome free, I gave up and am using bootstrap icons for these purposes.

Comment: Do you place the imports in TS or SCSS

Comment: In application.scss

Comment: I added an update section with the error I get when using your solution

Answer (score 1):

Pls, try the following:

```
@import "font-awesome.css";
```

It helped me to resolve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am working off of font-awesome cdn 5.9.0 and Rails 7.0.1.  When copy pasting links off of the font-awesome library it gives you something similar to,

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i>
<i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
```

RoR wont display these.

However if you add the class "fa" to most icons, or class "fab" to "fa-brands" icons, they then register and display as normal.

```
<i class="fa fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i>
<i class="fab fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
```

Not sure why, would love an explanation below.